# background band element generates blank page

Tags: jasper-reports

So the problem is, when im have the following config:

....

```
<background>
    <band height="702" splitType="Stretch">
    </band>
</background>
<title>
    <band height="2" splitType="Stretch"/>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="2" splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="2" splitType="Stretch"/>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="830" splitType="Stretch">
```

....
As a result i have only one page in pdf:
[one page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OM4ag.png)

And after adding textField element to background:

```
<background>
    <band height="702" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" forecolor="#DFDFDF">
                <printWhenExpression>true</printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
        </textField>
    </band>
</background>
```

Second blank page is appearing:

[second blank page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Daj9r.png)

How can i fix it?

Comment: Post the full JRXML.

Comment: Hi, isn't this the expected behavior ? Your background is greater than page height and there is no content in the text field. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: matthiasbe, what do you mean greater than page height? My page height was around 890, however height of background band is 702